# iPhone phonegap image disappearing after the phone sits for some time

Tags: iphone, ios, image, cordova, uiwebview

I am using phonegap 2.0.0 on iOS and using basically the stock image capture code. After the image is captured it is saved to the phone, the URI is saved to the database along with the rest of the items info and the image is displayed on the page.

All this is working on both iOS and android. The issue is that when the iOS phone is turned off and allowed to sit for a period of time (overnight) the images no longer display. The rest of the data is retrieved from the database and displayed but the images just show a black square where the image should be (indicating the info is still inn the database)

Does iOS rename images after being turned off and allowed to sit for a some time? any suggestions? if the phone is turned off and back on this does not happen.. only after the phone sits for some time...

this seems very  relevant...
[Capturing and storing a picture taken with the Camera into a local database / PhoneGap / Cordova / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anybody else having this issue the following code worked for me...

```
    function capturePhoto() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(movePic, onFail,{ quality : 70 });
}

function movePic(file){ 
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError); 
} 

function resolveOnSuccess(entry){ 
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
var myFolderApp = "myPhotos";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {      
fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                {create:true, exclusive: false},
                function(directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                },
                resOnError);
                },
resOnError);
}
function successMove(imageUri) {
    document.getElementById('smallImage').src = imageUri.fullPath;
    //hidden input used to save the file path to the database
    document.getElementById('site_front_pic').value = "file://"+imageUri.fullPath;
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed to load picture because: ' + message);
}

function resOnError(error) {
alert(error.code);
}
```